# Error 1109: unknown table ‘account’ in filed list

Tags: mysql, errors

When I inserted the values in new table, I had met a problem in there. The trigger will be shown below:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger validation_check before insert on exercise.account for each row
begin
  if (account.account_type <> 'normal' or account.account_type <> 'administrator'  or account.account_type <> 'guest') 
and (account.priority > 100 and account.priority < 0) 
  then signal SQLSTATE '45000'
  set message_text  = 'The type of account which you gave was invalid or the priority cannot be inserted!';
End if;
end $$
```

I tried and succeeded but when insert I meet an error 1109. I’m not sure which I wrong in this.

```
insert into exercise.account (accountID, account_type, priority) values 
("315","administrator","100"),
("422","normal","50"),
("22","guest","20");
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the given trigger.

1.You are using before insert trigger and you have to validate the values which will be inserted.

That can be done by using new.account_type  and new.priority .

2.The error about the unknown column account_type is because you need another pair of parenthesis and you need the keyword new.

```
((account.account_type <> 'normal' or account.account_type <> 'administrator'  or account.account_type <> 'guest') 
and (account.priority > 100 and account.priority < 0) )
```

3.All those or conditions can be written as not in , and here `account.priority > 100 and account.priority < 0` I think you need to use or instead of and. A number cant be greater than 100 and lower than 0 at the same time.

```
((new.account_type not in ('normal','administrator','guest'))  and (new.priority > 100 or new.priority < 0))
```

Some data examples which can be found on [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WbAHTFIh)  as well

```
CREATE TABLE account(
accountID INT,
account_type varchar(20),
priority int  );
```

Trigger

```
create trigger validation_check before insert on account 
 for each row
   begin
      if ((new.account_type not in ('normal','administrator','guest')) and (new.priority > 100 or new.priority < 0)) 
        then signal SQLSTATE '45000'
        set message_text  = 'The type of account which you gave was invalid or the priority cannot be inserted!';
      end if;
   end
```

The following data will be inserted without any error

```
insert into account (accountID, account_type, priority) values 
(315,'administrator',100),
(422,'normal',50),
(22,'guest',20);
```

Below insert will give

> The type of account which you gave was invalid or the priority cannot
> be inserted!

error.

```
insert into account (accountID, account_type, priority) values 
(1,'test1',300);
```

Comment: May you ask me clearly the important wrong make I have error in code. Why does use ’new.’ In trigger? Is it a problem that makes me error or not, please ?

Comment: @SarahPhan new are the values which will be inserted , and yes the missing  keword new does throw the error. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html